# kaminari ajax pagination not updating the paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I'm implementing pagination in rails3 using the kaminari gem.

I've been following this code from github
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_example/commits/ajax

unfortunately, the following code

```
jQuery('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@recipes,:remote=>true).to_s) %>');
```

does not seem to be working.

my javascript for what to do what a user selects a page is

```
  jQuery('a','nav.pagination').click(function(){
         // get the page value from href
          var page = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('/home/index?page=','');
          jQuery.getJSON('?page='+page, function(data){
                 for (var r in data){
                   results.push(data[r]);
          });
              showResults(results,(page-1)*10);
              jQuery('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@recipes,:remote=>true).to_s) %>');
  });
```

the showResults function runs through the JSON and creates a bunch of html elements. 
Everything is working great, except that the pagination isn't updating to show the current page when the results are reloaded.

I don't get any errors in firebug, i'm using Rails 3 with ruby 192.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have '#paginator' element for the paginator in you HTML?
I mean, does the following code return the element on Firebug?

```
jQuery('#paginator')
```

Comment: yes, firebug finds the id='paginator' no problem. Not sure why this isn't working. Though I'm considering replacing the 'paging links' with a slider anyway, so I might not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update result and paginate you need to update both at a time.
Paginate AJAX sends a request as JS so to handle them you should have action.js.erb file inside view folder. Perform two things here.

1) Update result

```
$("#issues").html("<%= j render(:partial => 'recipes') %>");
```

2) Update Paginate

```
$('.pagination').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@recipes, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

Find respective page attribute to update paginate. This will update result and paginate run time.